# Check if given IP is in given Network range or not in C

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, ip-address, subnet

I was asked this question in one of the interview and I was strictly asked to do programming in C/C++. I am not much into C++, I have tried writing code in C, can anyone help me improving my code, it works fine but I think it is not the best way to solve.

**Question: Check if given IP is in network range or not using C. For example: IP address: 192.168.0.1 and Network: 192.168.0.0/24** => Answer should be yes, it is in network range.

My Answer is as below, but can we improve this? ***Can anyone share their answer for this problem?***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *int_to_bin(unsigned short n){

  char *result = malloc(n);
  int c,k;
  char ch = '1';
  char ch1 = '0';
  for (c=7; c>=0; c--){
    k = n >> c; //Convert Integer to Binary by Right Shift Operation
    if(k & 1){
      strncat(result, &ch, 1);
    }
    else{
      strncat(result, &ch1, 1);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main(){
  unsigned short n1,n2,n3,n4;
  unsigned short m1,m2,m3,m4,m5;
  char ip[33];
  char sub[49];

  printf("Enter an IP address\n");
  scanf("%s",ip);
  sscanf(ip,"%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);

  printf("Enter a Subnet address\n");
  scanf("%s",sub);
  sscanf(sub,"%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu/%hu", &m1, &m2, &m3, &m4, &m5);

  char target[ 33 ];  //This variable will store the 1s and 0s after converting IP address into binary
  char target1[ 49 ]; //This variable will store the 1s and 0s after converting Subnet address into binary
  char *a = int_to_bin(n1);
  char *b = int_to_bin(n2);
  char *c = int_to_bin(n3);
  char *d = int_to_bin(n4);

  char *o = int_to_bin(m1);
  char *p = int_to_bin(m2);
  char *q = int_to_bin(m3);
  char *r = int_to_bin(m4);

  strcat(target, a);
  strcat(target, b);
  strcat(target, c);
  strcat(target, d);

  strcat(target1, o);
  strcat(target1, p);
  strcat(target1, q);
  strcat(target1, r);
  //printf("%s\n", target);
  //printf("%s\n", target1);

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<m5; i++){
    if(target[i] != target1[i]){
      printf("IP is not in Subnet range\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  printf("IP is in Subnet range\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use strings to do a bit mask?

Comment: IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers, and you need to use them that way, converting from a string to integer to calculate, then back to a string for the answer. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains.

Comment: @EmanuelP I am open to have some new method. Thanks for your response!!

Comment: For example, will your method correctly identify that `198.51.100.223` is an address in the `198.51.96.0/21` network?

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you for finding this bug. Actually I was using i<=m5 in my code in for loop at the end. It should be i<m5. This gives correct result now. I am converting decimal to binary and concatenating into the string and comparing between IP and subnet and matching the prefix. Do you think this is not a correct way to do so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is easier to just convert the strings (IP address, network, and mask) to 32-bit integers, bitwise `AND` the subject address integer with the mask integer, and compare the result of that to the network integer. If they are equal, then it is true.

Comment: The **IPv4 Network Address** section of the answer I linked explains that.

Comment: `char *result = malloc(n);` How is `n` related to the length of your resuling string? Also: Using `strncat` requires a valid string as first argument. A pointer to memory containing undefined content does not qualify for that purpose. The same holds for the second argument. The address of a single character without a terminating 0 byte is no valid string. All your uninitialized `char` arrays are not suitable for `strcat` as well.

Comment: @Gerhardh Seems like it is little bit tough for me to understand at this point as I am still clearing my concepts with Pointers and Memory allocation. Could you please help me converting your thoughts into a code? I really appreciate. TIA!

Comment: @RonMaupin I am trying to build the logic as per your suggestion, still if you can spare some time writing your solution here, that would be really awesome, I really appreciate!

Comment: Showing an example how to use your pointers properly would not really solve your problem as you mentioned to try as RonMaupin suggested with link. In that case there won't be any pointers allocated at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have done few changes and my code looks like as following. Please let me know if you think there is any bug in it:

1. I am taking input and using **sscanf** function, storing each octet into integer format.
2. Then using int_to_bin function, converting integer to binary using right shift operation and storing into character array.
3. Then I am doing **strcat** at the end to have combined array.
4. Then finally, using 'for' loop, I am doing prefix matching.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *int_to_bin(unsigned short n){

  char *result;
  int c,d,t;
  t=0;
  result = (char*)malloc(32+1);
  

  if (result == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  
  for (c=7; c>=0; c--){
    d = n >> c; //Convert Integer to Binary by Right Shift Operation
    if(d & 1){
      *(result+t) = 1 + '0';
    }
    else{
      *(result+t) = 0 + '0';
    }
    t++;
  }
  *(result+t) = '\0';
  return result;
}

int main(){
  unsigned short n1,n2,n3,n4;
  unsigned short m1,m2,m3,m4,m5;
  char ip[33];
  char sub[49];

  printf("Enter an IP address\n");
  scanf("%s",ip);
  sscanf(ip,"%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4); //This will store each octet in integer format

  printf("Enter a Network address\n");
  scanf("%s",sub);
  sscanf(sub,"%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu/%hu", &m1, &m2, &m3, &m4, &m5); //This will store each octet in integer format

  char target[ 33 ];  //This variable will store the 1s and 0s after converting IP address into binary
  char target1[ 49 ]; //This variable will store the 1s and 0s after converting Subnet address into binary
  char *a = int_to_bin(n1);
  char *b = int_to_bin(n2);
  char *c = int_to_bin(n3);
  char *d = int_to_bin(n4);

  char *o = int_to_bin(m1);
  char *p = int_to_bin(m2);
  char *q = int_to_bin(m3);
  char *r = int_to_bin(m4);

  strcat(target, a);
  strcat(target, b);
  strcat(target, c);
  strcat(target, d);

  strcat(target1, o);
  strcat(target1, p);
  strcat(target1, q);
  strcat(target1, r);
  //printf("%s\n", target);
  //printf("%s\n", target1);

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<m5; i++){
    if(target[i] != target1[i]){
      printf("IP is not in given Network range\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  printf("IP is in given Network range\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really do not want to do this with strings. Besides being much slower than integer math, you cannot determine things like first and last usable addresses, broadcast address, address offset into the network, etc. using strings. It is all math, and the only string manipulation should be address string to unsigned integer, perform the math, then back to string (if needed). The link I gave you has the algorithms for all the IP math for the various things you may want to do.